# When I run cypress tests in parallel, it starts only 1 machine and seems to run single threaded

Tags: cypress

When I run cypress tests in parallel, it starts only 1 machine and seems to run single threaded.

This is my run command with my Cypress enterprise cloud account, which supposedly allows more than 10 Users:

```
cypress run --record --parallel --key ${DASH_KEY} \
 --ci-build-id LOCAL_DOCKER --group PARALLEL_RUN
```

Is there a way to increase the number of "machines" being used in the cloud?

Test runs appear to use 1 "machine" per thread?  The `--parallel` option did not seem to enable more than 1 machine.   Is there a way to enable more than 1 machine?

The website docs have no information on this distinction between threads and machines.